# Nextjs Stripe Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to add data from stripe check out events to my orders database but stripe can't find the signature every time I try to test the web hook. Got me banging my head against the keyboard.

app/api/webhooks/checkout/route.ts

```
import Cors from "micro-cors";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse, } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import prisma from "@/prisma/utils";
import {  Users, Orders } from '@prisma/client';
import { sendEmail } from "@/email/utils";
import type { Readable } from 'node:stream';
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import getRawBody from "raw-body";
import { buffer } from "micro";



const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ["POST", "HEAD"],
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  }
}

const secret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET || "";



export async function POST(req: NextApiRequest) {
  try {
    const body = await buffer(req);

    // const body = rawbody.toString()
    
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']! as string;
    
    const event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body.toString(), sig!, secret);
    
    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      if (!event.data.object.customer_email) {
        throw new Error(`missing user email, ${event.id}`);
      } else {
        //if email exists then do some stuff

        const id = event.data.object.id
        const createdAt = new Date(event.data.object.created * 1000)

        const order = await prisma.orders.findUnique({
            where: {
                id,
            },
        });

        const email = event.data.object.customer_details!.email!

        const user = await prisma.users.findUnique({
          where: {
            email,
          }
        });

        const line_items = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
          id
        );

        console.log('line items:' + line_items)


        const products = JSON.stringify([
          line_items!.data.map((item: any) => {
            return {
              item: item.description, //defualts to name
              quantity: item.quantity,
              price: item.price,
            }
          })
        ])
    
        if(order){
            throw new Error(`order already exist, ${id}`);
        } else {
            await prisma.orders.create({ 
                data: {
                    id,
                    createdAt,
                    user_id: user!.id,
                    user_name: event.data.object.customer_details!.name!,
                    address: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.line1!,
                    address_2: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.line2!,
                    city: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.city!,
                    state: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.state!,
                    zip: Number(event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.postal_code!),
                    profit: Number(event.data.object.amount_total), 
                    shipped: false,
                    deliverd: false,
                    products,
                },
            });
        }
      }
    
      
    }
    
    return NextResponse.json({ result: event, ok: true });
  } catch (error) {
    
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "something went wrong",
        ok: false,
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried using the raw-body lib and it gives me an error:

> TypeError: argument stream must be a stream.

I've tried using buffer from the mirco lib and it gives me another error:

> HttpError: Invalid body and   originalError: TypeError: stream.on is not a function.

I've tried using just the plain body like `req.body` and it gives the original error:

> Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload.

I've tried using `body = req.text()` and switching the type of req from `NextApiRequest` to `Request`.
I've tried adding `bodyParser: false`.
I've tried changing     `const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']! as string;` to `const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature')!`.
I also tried `sig = headers.get('stripe-signature')`.

Comment: What version of Next are you using? Also have you tried using a buffer function like shown here:https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12517#discussioncomment-2929922 and seeing if it avoids the TypeError?

Comment: im using nextjs 14 and I tried it with the buffer function u sent just now it gave me this type error TypeError: readable is not async iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code it seems to be working now idk why.

```
import Cors from "micro-cors";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { NextResponse, } from "next/server";
import Stripe from "stripe";
import prisma from "@/prisma/utils";
import {  Users, Orders } from '@prisma/client';
import { sendEmail } from "@/email/utils";
import type { Readable } from 'node:stream';
import type { NextApiRequest } from "next";
import getRawBody from "raw-body";
// import { buffer } from "micro";



const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!);

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ["POST", "HEAD"],
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  }
}

// async function buffer(readable: Readable) {
//   const chunks = [];
//   for await (const chunk of readable) {
//     chunks.push(typeof chunk === 'string' ? Buffer.from(chunk) : chunk);
//   }
//   return Buffer.concat(chunks);
// }





export async function POST(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const body = await req.text();

    const secret = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE__WEBHOOK_SECRET;

    // const body = rawbody.toString()
     
    const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature')! as string;

    let event: Stripe.Event;
    
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig!, secret!);

    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      if (!event.data.object.customer_details!.email) {
        throw new Error(`missing user email, ${event.id}`);
      } else {
        //if email exists then do some stuff

        const id = event.data.object.id
        console.log('id:'+ id)
        const createdAt = new Date(event.data.object.created * 1000)

        const order = await prisma.orders.findUnique({
            where: {
                id,
            },
        });

        const email = event.data.object.customer_details!.email!

        const user = await prisma.users.findUnique({
          where: {
            email,
          }
        });

        const line_items = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(
          event.data.object.id
        );

        console.log('line items:' + line_items.data)


        const products = JSON.stringify([
          line_items!.data.map((item: any) => {
            return {
              item: item.description, //defualts to name
              quantity: item.quantity,
              price: item.price,
            }
          })
        ])
    
        if(order){
            throw new Error(`order already exist, ${id}`);
        } else {
            await prisma.orders.create({ 
                data: {
                    id,
                    createdAt,
                    user_id: user!.id,
                    user_name: event.data.object.customer_details!.name!,
                    address: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.line1!,
                    address_2: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.line2!,
                    city: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.city!,
                    state: event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.state!,
                    zip: Number(event.data.object.customer_details!.address!.postal_code!),
                    profit: Number(event.data.object.amount_total), 
                    shipped: false,
                    deliverd: false,
                    products,
                },
            });
            if(user){
                  await prisma.users.update({
                    where: {
                      email,
                    },
                    data: {
                      points: 10 * products.length,
                    }
                  })
            }
        }
      }
    
      
    }
    
    return NextResponse.json({ result: event, ok: true });
  } catch (error) {
    
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        message: "something went wrong",
        ok: false,
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: two main comments make it work: const body = await req.text(); and const sig = req.headers.get('stripe-signature')! as string;